# script in dijit linkpane does not execute

Tags: dojo

i have put some javascript in dijit linkpane. but it does not execute when i activate a linkpane.
code look as follows.

### test.html

```
<body class=" claro ">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="height:300px; width:500px">
        <a href="a.html" dojoType="dijit.layout.LinkPane" preload="false" refreshOnShow="true">Tab 1</a>
        <a href="b.html" dojoType="dijit.layout.LinkPane" preload="false" refreshOnShow="true">Tab 2</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

### a.html

```
<div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFun1()
        {
        alert("Coming soon...");
        }

    dojo.addOnLoad(testFun1);
    </script>
hello world!
</div>
```

### b.html

```
<div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFun2()
        {
        alert("Coming soon...");
        }

    dojo.addOnLoad(testFun2);
    </script>
bye world!
</div>
```

Kindly suggestion how this can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

Code to execute scripts can be found in dojox.layout.ContentPane.  LinkPane inherits from the more lightweight dijit.layout.ContentPane.  I guess you can put one of the dojox ContnetPanes inside a LinkPane.

Answer (score 0):

Set script type to `type="dojo/method"`

so we get (for A):

```
<div>
     <script type="dojo/method">
        function testFun1()
        {
        alert("Coming soon...");
        }

    dojo.addOnLoad(testFun1);
    </script>
hello world!
</div>
```

`type="text/javascript"` is not parsed by the dojo parser